# Querying for @Embedded map in objectify for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Please consider following sample

```
@Entity
public class Abc {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Unindexed
    private String name;

    @Embedded
    private Map<String, Xyz> objs;
}

public class Xyz {
    private String objName;
    private String objStatus;
}
```

Now I want the object of Abc such that `objs.get("someKey").getObjName().equals("someName")` is true.

How do I make this query in Objectify? Also, if I store 'objs' as list instead of map, can I query for an object of Abc such that one of the list values have objName as 'someName'? Need help in this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to query like this:

```
Objectify ofy = factory.begin
ofy.query(Abc.class).filter("objs.someKey.objName=", "someName")
```

The map keys are simple folded into the map of properties of the entity, using a dot as the separator and the name of the map field ("objs") as a prefix to avoid collisions.

Comment: What is the maximum number of key/value we can put in a Map that is serialized like this?

Comment: The regular Datastore limit applies, which is 1 MB after storing the values in Datastore's internal structures (a protocol buffer).

Note that this method is somewhat outdated, Objectify 4 has a different (but similar) approach to nested maps.

Comment: it will cost a lot though, considering if the map is indexed to be qureyable, since each index (for each extra key-value pair) will mean 2 more datastore writes